# Having difficulty with choosing a wide-angle lens for Canon

Tags: lens, canon, digital, wide-angle, canon-450d

I have got Canon 450D Kit and I would like to purchase a new Canon lens. Not too pricey. Main purposes are to shoot landscapes and portraits at the same time to have decent zoom.

I had a look at EF 17-40mm f/4L USM and EF 70-200mm f/4L IS USM. However they both are for different purposes. Is there any lens that is in between these two?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the question. Do you just mean "Does the [EF 24-70mm f/4L IS USM](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/ef_lens_lineup/ef_24_70mm_f_4l_is_usm) exist?" If so, _yes_.

Answer (score 3):

The L lenses you're looking at, and the 24-70/2.8L II and 24-105/4L IS USM, are designed *for full frame.*  The 17-40L is not meant to be a walkaround zoom on a crop (though you can certainly use it as one), it's designed to be an ultrawide zoom on full-frame.

You may want to consider the crop analogs to the 24-something L lenses, the [EF‑S 17-55/2.8](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-17-55mm-f-2.8-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx) and the [EF‑S 15-85 f/3.5-5.6 IS USM](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-15-85mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx).  If you're willing to compromise a little farther on image quality for a wider zoom range, there's also the [EF‑S 18-135 f/3.5-5.6 STM](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-18-135mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-STM-Lens-Review.aspx).

24mm, on a crop body like the 450D, is not particularly wide, and you might find it lacking for landscape use.  Look at the landscape shots you've taken with your kit lens and see how often you're using 18-24 before making the decision to go with a 24-105 or a 24-70.  And if you do go with a 24-something L, then you might also want to consider adding an ultrawide lens, like the EF-S 10-22 or Tokina 11-16/2.8 to fill in the wide end of the range on crop.

Ls are great, but they're the most expensive, heaviest, and largest of the Canon lenses. And [they aren't *that* much sharper than the gold-ringed USM lenses](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=675&Camera=736&Sample=0&FLI=0&API=0&LensComp=355&CameraComp=736&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=0&APIComp=0). Ls have better contrast, build, and usability features, but the image quality gap is narrower than some people think. They may cost three times more, but they're not three times sharper.  Buyer's remorse can hit particularly hard with a first L simply because of the price tag and inflated expectation. For example, the 24-105 is the 5D/6D kit lens. It's often considered to be a "compromise" lens--medium fast max. aperture, weak at the wide end (for a $1000 L zoom) when it comes to chromatic aberration and distortion.  No lens is perfect, not even an L.

Answer (score 1):

For an APS-C body the **EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS** lens provides the same wide angle Field of View (FoV) as the 24-70 f/2.8, 24-70 f/4 IS, or 24-105 f/4 IS do on a full frame camera, but also provides a 135mm equivalent full frame field of view on the long end. Yes you give up the faster f/4 (or f/2.8) constant apertures for a variable f/3.5-5.6 but you gain the extra reach. If you want a single lens that can go from wide angle for landscapes to short/medium telephoto for portraits it might be the compromise you are looking for.

If a 24-70 f/2.8 will fit your needs, consider the Tamron 24-70mm f/2.8 Di VC. It is rated better than the original Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L but not quite as good as the newer (and VERY pricey) EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L II. The current street price for the Tamron is less than half what the Canon "II" will set you back. And the "VC" is Tamron's Vibration Control, their equivalent of Canon's IS so you get both the benefit of faster apertures *and* slower minimum hand held shutter speeds with stationary subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for the Canon 24-105mm F/4L IS USM. The more expensive option is to have a brighter lens with a shorter reach, the Canon 24-70mm F/2.8L USM. Note that the former is stabilized, the latter is not.

The 24-105mm F/4L IS USM falls exactly between the two lenses, as you asked. So, obviously, it does not replace either but it will be a massive improvement over any kit-lens.

Answer (score 0):

According to [DPReview](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2014/05/13/canon-announces-16-35mm-f4l-and-10-18mm-f4-5-5-6-lenses), Canon has just announced..."an EF-S 10-18mm F4.5-5.6 IS STM wideangle zoom for APS-C SLRs, which gives a 16-29mm equivalent range. The 10-18mm is smaller, lighter and cheaper than the existing 10-22mm lens, and its stepping motor allows for fast and silent focusing while recording video."